# Symfony 4 project Production problems

Tags: php, apache, symfony, deployment, doctrine-orm

I guys, I am having some troubles deploying a Symfony project:

I run the command:

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

I used apache-pack:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

and this created one .htaccess inside public folder with the index.php.

-Assets couldn't be found. (Elements inside public folder):

```
GET http://buy-m3.infinityfreeapp.com/css/custom.css 
net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

-database connection trouble:

```
Request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: 
"An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] N
o such file or directory" at /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epighhg78813/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php 
line 112 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
No such file or directory at /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epghghgh878813/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:112)\n
[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
No such file or directory at /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epihghgh13/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18)
\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/vol6_3/epizy.com/epighgh8813/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:38)"} []
```

- dump-env prod:

```
// This file was generated by running "composer dump-env prod"

return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
  'APP_SECRET' => 'c84117fa77c8ghgghghhgds03',
  'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql:user:password@shost/dnbame',
);
```

I added an htacces at the application root too:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I could solve this problem with a lot of processes: first: composer require symfony/asset, and executing the common commands for deploy a symfony app such as composer require symfony/requirements-checker, composer dump-env prod( make sure to execute this command, it creates an env.*.php file with your .env.* information that it's required by the index.php from the public folder.  composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader and APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear. Overmore, I had to use webpack to manage the assets, there is the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Regards!.